# Prove that a limit doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

In my assignment I have to prove that the following function doesn't have a limit:

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x-\lfloor{\sin x}\rfloor}$$ when $${x \to 0}$$

In other words, I have to prove that for every $\delta$ such that $0<|x-{x_0}|<\delta,$ $|f(x)-L|>\epsilon$.

In fact, I don't even know how to start. Do I choose my $\delta$? I know that the sin function has certain values that's supposed to help me. How do I use it?

**I have to prove this by definition, so I can't use limit arithmetic for example**

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify where is the limit. In other words: where does $x$ tend?

Comment: I presume you mean "doesn't have a limit" at $x = 0$? In which case, looking at the left and right limits separately will help.

Comment: if x tends to infinty, the limit is 1

Comment: @James please see edit.

Comment: What is the function equal to for $x\in(0,\pi)$? What about $x\in(-\pi,0)$? Note that $\lfloor\sin x\rfloor$ is constant in each of those intervals.

Comment: For positive $x$ near $0$, $f(x)=x/x$. For negative $x$ close to $0$, $f(x)=x/(x-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I try to do in situations like this is to sketch a graph of the function in the neighborhood where the limit is evaluated.  In your case, it is not hard to see that when $x$ is sufficiently small and positive, $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor = 0$, for example.  So then $$f(x) = \frac{x}{x- \lfloor \sin x \rfloor}$$ in this region of $x$ will simply be equivalent to $x/x = 1$.

But for $x < 0$ but sufficiently close to $0$ (e.g., $x = -0.1$), $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor$ is no longer zero, but $-1$, because you are "rounding down."  Therefore, $f(x) = x/(x+1)$ in this region, and you can sketch the graph accordingly.

Now you can see that there is a jump discontinuity at $x = 0$.  Moreover, you can see that the discontinuity is of size $1$, which is formally represented by the fact that $$\left| \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) - \lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) \right| = 1.$$  That suggests a choice of $\epsilon < 1$ will work to prove the two-sided limit does not exist, since if, say, $\epsilon = 1/2$, you will not be able to find any $\delta$ such that the difference $|f(x) - L| < 1/2$ in the neighborhood of $x = 0$.  To formalize this reasoning is an exercise I leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of "limit" choose $\delta = \frac14$.  Then we will show that there is no combination of limit value $v$ and "small enough" $\epsilon > 0$ such that whenever $|x-0| < \epsilon$, 
$$\left| \frac{x}{x - \lfloor \sin x \rfloor} - v \right| < \delta
$$
If we show this, then the definition of a limit cannot be met and $f(x)$ has no limit as $x\to 0$.

First, consider positive $x$, and choose a "test" $x$ which is less than $\epsilon$ and also less than $\pi/4$.  For such an $x$,  $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$.  Note that within any $\epsilon$-neighborhood about zero, there are such values of $x$.  Thus if a suitable $v$ exists, we must have 
$$
\frac{3}{4} < v < \frac{5}{4}
$$

Next, consider negitive $x$, and choose a negative "test" $x$ which is greater than   $-\epsilon$ and also greater than $-\pi/4$.  For such an $x$,  $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor = -1$ and $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$.  But since $x > -\pi/4$, the denominator is positive and $f(x) < 0$.
(Again note that within any $\epsilon$-neighborhood about zero, there are such values of $x$.)

Thus if a suitable $v$ exists, we must have $v-\frac{1}{4} < 0$ or 
$$
v < \frac{1}{4}
$$

Since there are no numbers that are both less than $\frac14$ and at least $\frac34$, such a limit value $v$ cannot exist, and $f(x)$ has no limit.