# proof limit not exist using delta-epsilon

Tags: limits

i'm watching [Prove that a limit doesn't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277618/prove-that-a-limit-doesnt-exist) . and the answers and they're all fine but there is something that bugging me about "rounding down" i attach it below

"for $x < 0$ but sufficiently close to $0$ (e.g., $x = -0.1$), $\lfloor \sin x \rfloor$ is no longer zero, but $-1$, because you are "rounding down."  Therefore, $f(x) = x/(x+1)$"

and unfortunately people who answer this is no longer active , so can someone help me how that $rounding down" work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floor function rounds down to the closet integer less than or equal the given number.

For example $\lfloor (0.5) \rfloor =0 $

$\lfloor (-0.5) \rfloor =-1 $

Comment: can you give me more explanation, it's first time i hear that

Comment: There are two functions which picks integer values closest to a number. One takes the integer which is smaller or equal to the number and it is called the floor function. For example floor(3.2)=3. The other one is the ceiling function. For example ceiling (3.2)=4.